# How to pass a result from my java code to nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, node-java

I am writing an algo to analyze market data in Java, to visualize my data i'd like to make use of an existing charting library from tradingview. This free charting library runs on nodeJS.

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to populate it with my data resulting from my algorithm.

For example my Java code returns a "List< Candlestick >" object, how do i send this to the Javascript code running on the nodeJs ?

if someone would be so kind to give some global directions in how to approach this it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Just make a simple HTTP request? Create a route in [Node/express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html), call it from your Java app : `POST "/someNodeRoute"`, pass it your data.

Comment: depends on what kind of java codebase you have, if it's a rest service, it shouldn't be all that difficult

Comment: thanks for your suggesetion i will try the link you suggested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*My assumption here is that you have java code and the result you want to display is on nodejs.*

While at this moment calling data from the API is suggested, also there is one more option we can use to solve your problem. This is a good case of polyglot programming. I have used [graalvm](https://www.graalvm.org/).

Installation via sdkman
GraalVM

```
sdk install java 21.1.0.r11-grl
```

NodeJS

```
gu install nodejs
```

Both Main Projects are located here https://gitlab.com/graalvm-java-to-nodejs

- Java Project (has method which return a list)
- NodeJS Project(loads Java Class in NodeJS and call method on class reference to get the list)

Add any code to java library in my case I have a class which just return list of Point as given below:

```java
public class GraphData {
    public List<Point> getPoints() {
        return List.of(new Point(1, 1), new Point(3, 5));
    }
}
```

where `Point` is a POJO class to hold (x, y) value.

Clone this java project `https://gitlab.com/graalvm-java-to-nodejs/graalvm-simple-java` and execute `./gradlew clean build` this should give you a executable jar which can be executed java -jar file.jar command.

Now, clone `https://gitlab.com/graalvm-java-to-nodejs` and install dependencies `npm install` then execute
`node --jvm --vm.cp=/home/ashish/IdeaProjects/graavlvm/java-lib-gvm/build/libs/java-lib-gvm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar bin/www`

Relevant code which interacts with java is as below:

```js
var GraphDataJavaRef = Java.type('in.silentsudo.GraphData');
var graphData = new GraphDataJavaRef();
var data = graphData.getPoints();
```

`in.silentsudo.GraphData` class is loaded from the jar file which is provided to node program with argument named `--jvm --vm.cp path/to/file.jar`

Once you navigate to localhost:3000, you should see

```html
Express Tutorial
Welcome to Express Tutorial

Response from Java class
[Point{x=1, y=1}, Point{x=3, y=5}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear reply! i will give this a try too.